# Marking "old post reviews" with a banner

Tags: feature-request

Today I got [this review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/close/153758), and read through it. The already marked reason for closing, was to close it based on the "problem went away because of a typo", which—looking at the comments—seemed reasonable.

Before voting to close however, I took the time to look up the [Linux Mint releases information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_Mint_releases) to be able to provide a link, in a comment, asking the OP why one would want to install a version of Mint for which support ended in May 2014, intending to point out the risks of doing so in the comment. Only after looking that up did I see that the post for review was from 2013, which made making such a comment kind of inappropriate.

Recently it looks like some background process digs up such old posts for review, or else it seems that someone systematically goes over older stuff. That is fine, and I don't mind doing the reviews as they trickle in, but it would be nice to have some banner more clearly indicating that these are old posts brought up for clean-up. Assuming some automated process inserts these old posts in the review queue, can we get such a banner?

The alternative is that I constantly put up my glasses while reviewing. The low contrast light-gray colored date information (on a light-blue background) is just beyond the edge of what I can comfortably read on my computer screen with my old eyes. (Normal black on white text I can still read, but for how long?).

Comment: I'm one of the people who's digging up this older stuff. I have a SEDE query that's helping me find Q's that were either answered in comments or are possible candidates for closure, in order to clean the site up a little.

Comment: First of all thanks for the good work. I still hope we might get something along the lines we have when there is a new answer to an old question. In this case something like: "You are reviewing an old question now considered for closing" based on e.g posts older than a year.

Comment: Since I'm partly responsible for this, I'd like to make it easier everyone. If I put some sort of comment on the VTC'd post, would it help? You may still have to click to expand the comments, but then it would be more immediately obvious that it was an old post.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't think that helps much. As you indicate, it might not be seen without unfolding. I'll keep my glasses at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this as a user stylesheet might help, though unfortunately would require yearly maintenance. JavaScript could do a proper date test and eliminate the maintenance.

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stackexchange.com") {
  span.relativetime[title^="200"],
  span.relativetime[title^="2010"],
  span.relativetime[title^="2011"],
  span.relativetime[title^="2012"],
  span.relativetime[title^="2013"],
  span.relativetime[title^="2014"],
  span.relativetime[title^="2015"]
  {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to look at this but first need to figure out how to splice in a user defined stylesheet.

Comment: @Anthon I use Stylish, which is available for both Firefox and Chrome.